# Cannot find the log file written by java function called from sql

Tags: sql

I have created a function to generate pdf file of the input text file. This function calls a java class TextToPDFGenerator to generate pdf file. The java class is returning false and I am not sure where it is failing. Want to go through the log file, but I dont know where the log file for this java class is written. Where should I look for the log file. Please advice.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: im using pl/sql developer